# MySql nested select from the same table with the results

Tags: php, mysql, select, nested

I'm trying to do nested mysql query but I'm failing
it's as simple as I have a table called 'todo' which is for saving to-do list
when I do 
well this code is just to show how I wanna do it logically , I know it doesn't work 
and I think it probably needs JOIN or UNION but I couldn't do it

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT type FROM todo WHERE user = '$username' GROUP BY type");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<td>- <a href="list.php?type='.$row['type'].'">'."  ".$row['type'].'</a></td>';
    echo "</br>";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT titleFROM todo WHERE type= '$row['type']'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        echo '<td>-- <a href="todo.php?type='.$row['title'].'">'."  ".$row['title'].'</a>
    }
</td>';
echo "</br>";
}
```

I want the result to like 
-Work
 --Mr Jack
 --Company
-School
  --Android Class
  --Entrepreneurship
  --php development

and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop overwrites the outerloop's `$row` variable. Try using a different variable name in the inner loop. Also, there's an error in your inner loop's SQL query (missing space between the tablename and `FROM` keyword).

Comment: Here's the solution `code $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT type FROM todo WHERE user = '$username' GROUP BY type");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<td>- <a href="list.php?type='.$row['type'].'">'."  ".$row['type'].'</a></td>';
echo "</br>";
$type = $row['type'];
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT title FROM todo WHERE type= '$type' AND user = '$username' ");
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
echo '<td>-- <a href="todo.php?type='.$row2['title'].'">'."  ".$row2['title'].'</a>

</td>';
echo "</br>";
}}`

Comment: Glad I could help. You should also check your HTML for errors (`</br>` is not correct, `<br />` is). Please use the upvote answer option, or even set the answer as correct.